# Knight on a $3\times 4$ board: Hamiltonian graphs

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, hamiltonicity

A chess knight sits on a $3\times 4$ board. Is it possible for the knight to jump into the $12$ squares without jumping twice in any of them and ending and starting in the same box? What if it starts and ends in the different boxes?

I have drawn the graph that represents this problem and by looking at it I know that the answer to the first question is that it is impossible, but the second one is possible. However I can't find a mathematical reasoning to prove this. I know that my problem is equivalent to finding a hamiltonian cycle in the first case and a hamiltonian path in the second, but I don't know how to do this in any other way that trying to draw different paths. Could someone please help me with the mathematical reasoning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's number the squares on the board in the conventional way:

```
a4 b4 c4
a3 b3 c3
a2 b2 c2
a1 b1 c1
```

If we look at squares `a1`, `b4`, and `c1`, there are only two possible moves from each of them. If these squares are in the middle of a tour - and that's always the case for a closed tour - then both of those moves have to be part of the tour: one entering the square and one leaving.

However, putting those two moves together gives a cycle of length $6$: `a1` - `b3` - `c1` - `a2` - `b4` - `c2` - `a1`. Instead of a tour that visits all $12$ squares, we end up with two subtours: this cycle, and its mirror image `a4` - `b2` - `c4` - `a3` - `b1` - `c3` - `a4`. So a closed tour is impossible.

For an open tour, we can just pick a move, such as `a3` - `c2`, that goes between the two cycles of length $6$, and use it to stitch them together into a path. Just finding a path that works should be enough for a complete solution to this part.

Answer (score 1):

It is well-known that a [closed knight's tour on $3\times 4$-board is impossible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knight%27s_tour#Existence). I'll try to recall the proof.

An open tour exists, see, for instance, the picture below.

[image]